# Laravel Undefined variable Error

Tags: laravel

I'm getting this error

[image: I'm getting this error]

My Controller:

[image: My Controller]

Comment: Where code is supplied as bitmaps, it is not compatible with screen-readers, clipboards and search engines, and is treated as off-topic. Please supply these in a block of text using the formatting tool provided.

Answer (score 0):

In controller after student save add following

```
$success='student data updated';
return view('your_view_name',compact('success','student'));
```

if your view name is inside resources/views/student.blade.php you should write like this

```
return view('student',compact('success','student'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass `$student` variable for view, You need to pass it like:

```
 return view()->route('student.index',compact('student'))->with('success','Student data updated.');

// OR

 return view()->route('student.index',['student'=>$student])->with('success','Student data updated.');
```

Details Here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing

Answer (score 0):

You must return the student variable to blade file using compact functionality

```
return view('student.index', compact('student'))->with('success','Student data updated.');
```

and one more thing is you can Use HTML entities to escape curly braces to set the value of input. like

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" value="{{$student->first_name}}">
```